# Square markers in Leaflet for R

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, r-leaflet

In JS Leaflet, you can create a divIcon that is square and in the colour of your choice, for example this square purple marker:
[image]

How can this be achieved in Leaflet for R? Bonus question: how can the colour depend on a property value from geojson data? In the example here, the value name is "value".

Here is a MVE for JS Leaflet that I would like to replicate in R:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>A Leaflet map!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css"
        integrity="sha512-Rksm5RenBEKSKFjgI3a41vrjkw4EVPlJ3+OiI65vTjIdo9brlAacEuKOiQ5OFh7cOI1bkDwLqdLw3Zg0cRJAAQ=="
        crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.js"
        integrity="sha512-/Nsx9X4HebavoBvEBuyp3I7od5tA0UzAxs+j83KgC8PU0kgB4XiK4Lfe4y4cgBtaRJQEIFCW+oC506aPT2L1zw=="
        crossorigin="">
    </script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/esri-leaflet@2.2.4/dist/esri-leaflet.js"
    integrity="sha512-tyPum7h2h36X52O2gz+Pe8z/3l+Y9S1yEUscbVs5r5aEY5dFmP1WWRY/WLLElnFHa+k1JBQZSCDGwEAnm2IxAQ=="
    crossorigin=""></script> 
  <style>
    body {margin: 0}
    #map{ 
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #FFF;
    }
    .layer-1-icon {
        background-color: #bf00ff;
    }
    .layer-1-label {
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
        box-shadow: none;
        color: #282828;
        padding: 2px;
        border: none;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .leaflet-tooltip-top:before,
    .leaflet-tooltip-bottom:before,
    .leaflet-tooltip-left:before,
    .leaflet-tooltip-right:before {
        position: absolute;
        pointer-events: none;
        border: 0px;
        background: transparent;
        content: "";
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="map"></div>

  <!-- IMPORT OUR GEOJSON FILES -->
  <script>
var data = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [9.400038162145233,56.09709088979111]
      },
          "properties": {
        "Value": 76205,
        "Name": "A transformer"
      },
      "id": 0
    }]}
  </script>

  <script>
    // initialize the map
    var map = L.map('map').setView([56.09709088979111, 9.400038162145233], 10);

    // load a tile layer (docs here: https://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/api-reference/layers/basemap-layer.html)
    var esri_streets = L.esri.basemapLayer("Streets").addTo(map);

    lyr1 = L.geoJSON(data, {
        //minZoom: 10,  <- Min zoom is NOT available for geoJSON layers. We need to control this ourselves in our map.on zoomend function
        onEachFeature: function (f, l) {
            l.bindPopup('<pre>'+JSON.stringify(f.properties,null,' ').replace(/[\{\}"]/g,'')+'</pre>');
            l.bindTooltip(f.properties.Name.toString(), {
                permanent: false,
                className: 'layer-1-label',
            })
        },
        pointToLayer: function(feature, latLng) {
            return L.marker(latLng, {
                icon: L.divIcon({
                    className: "layer-1-icon",
                    iconSize: 14,
                })
            })
        }
    }).addTo(map);

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is a MVE in R, where I've been playing around with iconCreateFunction =   JS("...") to try and get the desired effect:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(geojsonio)
library(jsonlite)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("mymap",width="100%"),

  tags$head(tags$style(HTML(
    ".layer-1-icon {
        background-color: #bf00ff;
      }"
  )))
)

data <- data.frame(name='A transformer',lat=56.097,lon=9.400,
                   value= 76205, `Voltage level`= 60000)
geojson_data <- geojson_sp(geojson_list(data, lat='lat', lon='lon'))

server <- function(input, output) {

  leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>%
    setView(9.4, 56.3, 8 ) %>%
    addMarkers(data=geojson_data,
               layerId = 1, group='Stationer',
               label = ~name,
               labelOptions = labelOptions(permanent=F),
               clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(
                 iconCreateFunction =   JS("
                     function(cluster) {
                       return new L.DivIcon({
                         html: '<div><span>' + cluster.getChildCount() + '</div><span>',
                         className: 'layer-1-icon'
                       });
                     }
                     ")
               )
    )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: is it working for you?

Answer (score 0):

Recycling example from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54978367/custom-markers-with-different-shapes-and-colors-in-leaflet-r). We just need to create an icon and then pass it as argument inside the function `addMarkers`.

```
library(leaflet)

# data
set.seed(2015)
lat1 = 36 + runif(n = 5, min = -1, max = 1)
lon1 = -115 + runif(n = 5, min = -1, max = 1)

lat2 = 35 + runif(n = 5, min = -0.5, max = 0.5)
lon2 = -110 + runif(n = 5, min = -0.5, max = 0.5)

lat3 = 34 + runif(n = 5, min = -0.5, max = 0.5)
lon3 = -112 + runif(n = 5, min = -0.5, max = 0.5)


data_all = rbind(
  data.frame(
    Longitude = lon1,
    Latitude = lat1,
    Group = 1
  ),
  data.frame(
    Longitude = lon2,
    Latitude = lat2,
    Group = 2
  ),
  data.frame(
    Longitude = lon3,
    Latitude = lat3,
    Group = 3
  )
)

# icon
square_green <-
  makeIcon(iconUrl = "https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/green-square-1.png",
           iconWidth = 18,
           iconHeight = 18)
# map
data_all %>%
  leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(
    lng = ~ Longitude,
    lat = ~ Latitude,
    icon = ~ square_green
  )
```